# how to find similarity between image patches/windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to compare the similarity between one reference window(patch) and all other windows(patches) taken from an image. My code is given below.

Can anyone please help me evaluate the similarity between 'ref' (reference window) and all other 10000 windows given by variable 'test'? thank you

Detailed explanation: 
I tried doing using for loop. it is time-consuming. I tried to use the built-in function "ssim" but it says the dimension of tensors do not match. please suggest any method to do this batch processing

```
# Read grayscale image from file.
    Im = Image.open("cameraman.png") 
#Resize it to desired shape (h,w)
    Im = Im.resize((100,100))
# expand dimensions to get the shape [ no of batches, height, width, channel]
    Im = np.expand_dims(Im,axis=0)
    Im = np.expand_dims(Im,axis=0)
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(Im)
    x=tf.reshape(x,[1,100,100,1])  # this is the required image shape in a tensor

# Break one image into windows of 11x11 (overlapping)

    wsize=11
    ws=50  # Index of centre window (this window is reference window)

#Extract windows of 11 x 11 around each pixel
    p1=tf.extract_image_patches(x,sizes=[1,wsize,wsize,1],strides=[1,1,1,1],rates=[1,1,1,1],padding="SAME")

    patches_shape = tf.shape(p1)
    test=tf.reshape(p1, [tf.reduce_prod(patches_shape[0:3]), 11, 11, ])  # returns [#window_patches, h, w, c] 

    print(test.shape)  #test has shape [ 10000, 11,11]
    ref=test[5000,]    # this is the reference window of shape [ 1, 11,11]
    ref=tf.reshape(ref,[1,11,11])
    print(im1.shape)

The following statement says size mismatch:
    ssim1 = tf.image.ssim(ref, test, max_val=255, filter_size=11,filter_sigma=1.5, k1=0.01, k2=0.03) 

**ValueError: Shapes (1, 11, 11) and (10000, 11, 11) are incompatible.**
```

I expect the distance between each of these windows and the reference to be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to align the first dimension. You can either iterate over your 10000 image batch or broadcast your original patch. However, from a performance perspective, it is recommended to iterate over them by using `tf.map_fn()`.

Furthermore, you need to expand the last dimension, bc `tf.image.ssim` expects a third order tensor.
Here is a working example tested with tf 2.0 and eager execution:

```
arr1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([10000, 11, 11, 1]), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
arr2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([1, 11, 11, 1]), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

result_tensor = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.image.ssim(arr2[1:], x, 1), arr1)
```

The result tensor has the shape [10000, 0]. To get the mean call `tf.reduce_mean`.

However, pls revise the filter shape of 11x11 for a 11x11 patch and provide a working example next time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the convincing explanation and  the solution codes. I am just a beginner in tensorflow. So the map function was new to me.